# Average number of observation for group conditional on second identifier in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame that has the following structure

```
V1   V2

X1   Y1
X1   Y2
X2   Y2
X2   Y2
X3   Y4
X3   Y5
X3   Y5
X4   Y6
X4   Y6
X4   Y6
```

I want to calculate the average number of pairs between `V1` and `V2` for `V1` in `data.table`. The end results should look like this and contains the average number of observed pairs of V1.

```
V1   avg.num.pairs

X1    1.0
X2    2.0
X3    1.5
X4    3.0
```

Any elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: Average of what? It's a string. You mean the numeric part of the string?

Comment: Basically, the average number of pairs for V1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(V1) %>%
 summarise(V2 = n()/n_distinct(V2))

  V1       V2
  <chr> <dbl>
1 X1      1  
2 X2      2  
3 X3      1.5
4 X4      3
```

The same with `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)[, .(V2 = .N/uniqueN(V2)), by = V1]
```

Comment: Thanks! It does the job but I would prefer a `data.table` solution because I would like to avoid working with different frameworks.

Comment: Updated with a `data.table` solution :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple base R solution is to use `aggregate`, i.e.,

```
dfout <- aggregate(V2 ~ V1,df, function(x) length(x)/length(unique(x)))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  V1  V2
1 X1 1.0
2 X2 2.0
3 X3 1.5
4 X4 3.0
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("X1", "X1", "X2", "X2", "X3", "X3", "X3", 
"X4", "X4", "X4"), V2 = c("Y1", "Y2", "Y2", "Y2", "Y4", "Y5", 
"Y5", "Y6", "Y6", "Y6")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```